# An error occurred: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON (ASP.NET, React Js)

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net

This code is part of an ASP.NET Core web application and defines a TestController that handles the HTTP GET request.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("ProcessString")]
    public IActionResult ProcessString([FromQuery] string inputString)
    {
        var result = new { Result = inputString };
        return Ok(result);
    }

}
```

The code is a React component for the web interface

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function TestClient() {
    const uri = 'api/Test/ProcessString';
    const [inputString, setInputString] = useState('');
    const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

    const sendRequest = () => {
        fetch(`${uri}?inputString=${inputString}`, {
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
                setResponse(data.Result);
            })
        .catch(error => {
                console.error('An error occurred:', error);
            });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={inputString} onChange={(e) => setInputString(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={sendRequest}>Send Request</button>
            <div>
                <strong>Response:</strong> {response}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TestClient;
```

Every time I click on the button I get an error
An error occurred: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
What could be the reason?

Comment: The error is because your API endpoint is returning HTML/XML (most likely from an error message) not JSON as you've told the JS to expect. You need to debug your server side code to see why that's happening

Comment: Also debug your javascript to see what status code is returned.

Comment: Instead of Ok(), use the Json() IActionResult from the controller. This will add the necessary headers and convert your objects to JSON in the response.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that your request expects JSON to receive due to the

```
Accept: 'application/json',
```

specification but instead it receives some HTML, clearly indicated by the Doctype content. So either your request does not reach the action you wanted to target, or errors out or your action responds with HTML rather than JSON.

Open the Network tab of your Dev Tools and check what you have in the response tab of the request that you have sent (if you just opened the dev tools, repeat your test to get new requests in there). That might be already enough info to solve your problem.

Look into what HTML you are receiving. It may be an error message, telling you what's wrong. Then proceed looking at the server logs and possibly debugging your app.